# login not working using hash_pbkdf2

Tags: authentication, hash, php

i am storing the password using hash_pbkdf2 but now ive hit on a problem

my code :

1.for register

```
    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(125);//salt
    $final_pass = hash_pbkdf2("sha512",$pass,$salt,1,125);//where $pass is the password entered by the user
```

2.for login

```
   $found_pass=$row['salt'];//retrieve the salt in the db
   $final_pass= hash_pbkdf2("sha512",$password,$found_salt,1,125);
```

the login does not seem to work why is that?if anybody can help me

Comment: It might just be a typo in the code in the question, but above you assign to `$found_pass` where you retrieve the salt from the db, but use `$found_salt` where you try and use it on the next line.

Comment: @danielpsc found salt is the salt retrieved from the db and i allready tried it but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, Lord.

Look, Mr.coder. No disrespect, but if that code is going to production environment, then please ask somebody else to do it. I know we all have to start somewhere, but this is not where production *security* code should start. Having that said, let's address your question.

---

First of all, you're using [`hash_pbkdf2`](https://php.net/hash_pbkdf2), which is a PHP 5.5 function. Since you're already coding for PHP 5.5, it's better to use the [`password_hash`](https://php.net/password_hash) API. You only need two inputs for `password_hash`; the password, and the algorithm (`PASSWORD_BCRYPT` is recommended). The output is one string containing everything you need (the automatically-generated salt, the password, the algorithm and the iterations). You take that string and store it in the database.

Second, you're using one iteration. What's the point? You want to make the process as slow as possible, while keeping it as usable as possible. One iteration is extremely low. Start with 1000 as a bare minimum.

Third, what's with the gigantic salt? Anything higher than 128 bits (16 bytes) is unnecessary.

For verification (login), you only need one method; [`password_verify`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). You give the hash string (from the database), and the password. The output is either `true` for successful verification, or `false` for failed verification. Here's an example:

```
//Register
$hashString_ToTheDB = password_hash($userPass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

//Login
$isCorrectPassword = password_verify($userPass, $hashString_FromTheDB);
```

Comment: the hash value generated is a little small is it secure enough?and go easy on me im only 15

Comment: @Mr.coder The digest of the password itself is 184 bit. It's more than just secure enough.